# String to int from deduced vector of strings filled by a function

Tags: c++, vector, c++17

I have a string `111;222;333` which I want to convert to three integers.

First I split the string

```
std::vector<std::string> split(...){ ... };
```

The return values are stored in `vector` of deduced type

```
std::vector splitVals {split(...)};
```

If I then want to convert the values to integer like so

```
int foo1 {std::stoi(splitVals[0])};
```

The `stoi` function is complaining, because the deduced type of the vector is `std::vector<std::vector<std::string>, std::allocator<std::vector<std::string>>>`, but if I don't let the type to be deduced, everything works as intended.

```
std::vector<std::string> splitVals {split(...)};
int foo1 {std::stoi(splitVals[0])};
```

`std::stoi` now can work because the input value is `std::string`. The issue seems to start with the vector being initialized from a function which returns the `std::vector<std::string>`. Is there a way to benefit from C++17 class template argument deduction, without these limitations?

Comment: My personal recommendation (going beyond the answer given): Don't use uniform initialisation *at all*, prefer classic (round) parentheses instead. While there was a good intention behind UI, the way it was realised it introduced far more trouble than it solved...

Comment: @Aconcagua Dunno, I have seen some talks from Nicolai Josuttis (a long time member of C++ standard committee) and he thinks, this should be a preffered method of initialisation (all of its remaining issues are, according to him, fixed in C++20)

Comment: Well, members of standard committee somehow *need* to stand behind such modifications. If the issues really get fixed, fine, but I doubt, though. To solve my 'favourite' issue, it would be necessary to make double braces mandatory when using an initialiser list (`std::vector<int> v{{7, 10, 12}};`), but that would break backwards compatibility. Well, let's see. In the end, you'll have to make up your own mind; with *current* state of the art, mine is settled, though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't use brace initialization. It favors the `std::initializer_list` constructor, and so the vector is deduced as holding sub-vectors for elements. Using parentheses should clear it right up.

```
std::vector splitVals (split(...));
```

Now the copy deduction guide is favored and the type held by the vector should be deduced as `std::string`.

Answer (score 2):

Wow. 8 upvotes and accepted answer. So, basically nothing more to add . . .

I just want to come back to the underlying mentioned task:

> I have a string 111;222;333 which I want to convert to three integers.

This a typical example for parsing for a CSV. And this can be easily done with a one-liner (one statement). Using `std::transform` and `sregex_toke_iterator`.

For completeness, I will show the code for that.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    // The test data
    std::string data("111;222;333;444");

    // Here we will see the result
    std::vector<int> values{};

    // This we will look up in the string
    std::regex re("(\\d+)");

    // Put all tokens into vector
    std::transform(
        std::sregex_token_iterator(data.begin(), data.end(), re, 1), 
        std::sregex_token_iterator(),
        std::back_inserter(values),
        [](const std::string& s){ return std::stoi(s); }
    );

    // Show debug output    
    std::copy(values.begin(),values.end(),std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout,"\n"));

    return 0;
}
```